# SED Command not executing through JAVA code

Tags: java, shell, sed

I am trying to execute the `sed` command from my Java code .The command basically is replacing the word "java" by "python" everywhere in the file OIMV2Migration.sh.

The code snippet I am using is:

```
String [] replaceTextInOIMscipt = {"sed" , "'s:java:python:g'" ,OIMV2Migration.sh"};

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(replaceTextInOIMscipt);
```

This piece of code is not doing any changes on the OIMV2Migration.sh file.

Comment: Try: `{"sed" , "-i", "'s:java:python:g'"... `

Comment: Tried.Not wokring even now.

Comment: Which platform is this on? Specifically, are you using GNU sed?

Comment: It is on linux.

Comment: @SurbhiMittal, have you tried the solution I posted below? If yes and it was helpful, please consider upvoting and accepting.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because your `sed` script is invalid. It starts with a single quote character, `'`, which is not a valid `sed` command. You want it to start with `s`, in your case:

```
String [] replaceTextInOIMscipt = {"sed", "s:java:python:g", "-i", "OIMV2Migration.sh"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(replaceTextInOIMscipt);
```

Also, you're missing the `-i`/`--in-place` flag to edit the file in place.